# Bootstrap 4 cards and sidebar row/cols

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I'm really new into the world of front-end(i'm a backend dev)

I feel like i have struggled a bunch, to make what i really wants to.
(Look at this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXyZd.png)))

So as you can tell, i'm trying to figure out Bootstrap grid/rows/cols.

The cards are used as a "product showcase", where i'll loop it from the database.
The sidebar, is to show what the user has selected, so it's important that the sidebar won't be touched.

I've googled several hours, and i can't figure it out..

Do someone here maybe have an example?

KR

Comment: What is your actual question? How to select an item from your products and show details in the sidebar?

Comment: Start with the Bootstrap docs: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/ Once you have attempted something show it here and explain the issue and what specifically is not working.